# Video not rendered in Webview using Licode Demos , it shows video icon only

Tags: android, ssl, webview, video-streaming, webrtc

I try to play video in android webview, but video couldn't play. In webview only the video icon appears.
I am trying different option i have tried apprtc in webview video played. But when i use licode demo in webview video didn't rendered in webview.

Without bypassing the ssl certification it shows a white screen.
I have bypassed ssl certification. It displays the video icon in the screen.But the issue remains the same video couldn't be played in webview.
I have tested this on oreo version and lollipop version.

```
WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    String url = "https://vid-stream.zemcar.com/room?id=5bcee60ac0072478e0bfa4c6";
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }
            message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?.. YES";

            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
                  } else {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                    Log.e("Error", request.toString());
                   }
                 }
              }
          ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any luck solving this one?